# Filling a char Array with a string from user Input

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

The Code reverses a Char Array. For Example if i write: 
char str[] = "Reverse";
it will return "esreveR" in the Console, now i want to know,if and how i can fill it with a string?

What i tried was : char str[] = userInput; (But it obv. didnt work...)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 using std::cout;
 using std::endl;

void reverse(char* target) //Requirements specify to have this argument
{
cout << "Before :" << target << endl; // Print out the word to be reversed
if (strlen(target) > 1) // Check incase no word or 1 letter word is placed
{
    char* firstChar = &target[0]; // First Char of char array
    char* lastChar = &target[strlen(target) - 1]; //Last Char of char array
    char temp; // Temp char to swap
    while (firstChar < lastChar) // File the first char position is below the last char position
    {
        temp = *firstChar; // Temp gets the firstChar
        *firstChar = *lastChar; // firstChar now gets lastChar
        *lastChar = temp; // lastChar now gets temp (firstChar)
        firstChar++; // Move position of firstChar up one
        lastChar--; // Move position of lastChar down one and repeat loop
    }
}
cout << "After :" << target << endl; // Print out end result.
}




 int main()
{
std::string userInput;
std::cin >> userInput;
char str[] = userInput; // <- This is the Key Part of my Question.
reverse(str);
 }
```

Comment: Actually, this is answered in several places. Check out: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/4422/

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `userInput` is a `std::string`, and your function expects a `char *`.

Without going into how to change that for better code, to get the string as a `char *`:

```
char *str = new char[userInput.length() + 1];
strcpy(str, userInput.c_str());
```

Just don't forget to `delete str;` in the end.